# Sencha Ext JS: How to set multiple defines in same file?

Tags: extjs

I tried to write multiple defines like this:

```
Ext.define('ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    mixins: ['ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocField'],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            this.updateAfterRender();
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocTextField', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.TextField',
    mixins: ['ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocField'],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            this.updateAfterRender();
        }
    }
});
```

in the page `ExtDoc/views/extfields/ExtDocPanel`, but I got error: `object expected`. And now I tried like this:

```
Ext.define('ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: ['ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocField'],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            this.updateAfterRender();
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.TextField',
    alias: ['ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocField'],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(){
            this.updateAfterRender();
        }
    }
});
```

but got same error. How can I do that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. The first version should be correct and working, the second should give the warning `[Ext.define] Duplicate class name 'ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocPanel' specified, must be a non-empty string`. Cannot help you without further input (ExtJS version, stack trace from browser error etc).

Comment: @Alexander the error said that he cant find ExtDoc/views/extfields/ExtDocTextField.js
because when i used Ext.create(...) he go to ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocTextField

Comment: When you define multiple classes in a single file, one of them is the "master" after which the file is named. You always have to `require` that master first, before instantiating any of the classes, so the file is already loaded when the non-master classes are instantiated.

Comment: @Alexander so i need to require what?

Comment: The master after which the file is named - if the file is `ExtDoc/views/extfields/ExtDocPanel.js`, then you would have to require `'ExtDoc.views.extfields.ExtDocPanel'`